# noscript tag or javascript

Tags: javascript, noscript

I want to show information about JavaScript is enabled or disabled in visitor's browser. But i am confuse in two ways to do this.

Method 1:

```
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript</noscript>
```

Method 2:

```
<div id='jsInfo'>Please enable JavaScript</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById('jsInfo').style.display='none';
</script>
```

Comment: ...and the one million dollar question is?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 1):

Either way works. I personally prefer the first as it is cleaner and maximizes compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

The `<noscript>` method is the *traditional* way of printing a message if JavaScript is disabled, which many people have used for many years....

The latter will only hide the message in the `<div>`, *if* JavaScript is **enabled**, therefore accomplishing the same thing.

It's two ways of doing the same thing - there are more, too. I always favour simplicity when the requirement is simple, so in my opinion the top option is best... *if that is what you're asking*

Answer (score 0):

The latter gives you more fine grained control. With regard to SEO the former is the better solution.